# Вызов события click на HTML странице через C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Интересует такой вопрос.

Есть сайта с полем ввода и кнопкой.
Через JS, у кнопки, ловится событие click. Далее JS берет значение, введенное пользователем, из поля ввода и пишет его в соседний div.

Вопрос заключается в том, каким образом, используя C# и исключительно средства .NET, можно зайти на сайт, заполнить форму и нажать на кнопку, чтобы потом считать получившийся результат из соседнего поля div.

Желательно реализовать данный функционал через консоль.

В интернете много вариантов использования GET POST запросов, а также сторонних библиотек из NUGET, но это не мой вариант, так как ни GET, ни POST запросы в момент нажатия не создаются.

Comment: `зайти на сайт, заполнить форму и нажать на кнопку` Все это в своей программе на C# или стороннем браузере? Если на странице вся обработка ведется через JS не создавая запросы на сервер, то можно посмотреть логику работы на JS и реализовать ее на C#.

Comment: Смотрите в браузере в отладчике, какая функция вызывается по `click()`, смотрите ее код. Так же, здесь важен контекст, что именно браузер вам считает? Где он берет данные для расчета, получает с сервера? Вопрос сильно обфусцирован, нужна максимальная конкретика. На данный момент дать объективный ответ невозможно.